# Списки в словари Python

Tags: python, словари

Есть 2 списка. С одинаковым количеством значений.

```
spis_1 = ["qwerty","trash"]
spis_2 = ["80","1337"]
```

На выходе нужно получить "объедение" этих двух списков,т.е -

```
spis_results = ["qwerty:80","trash:1337"]
```

Как это сделать ? 
Я пытался сделать через "превращение" в словарь ,вот таким образом.

```
dicts = [dict(zip(spis_1, spis_2))]
```

У меня конечно вышло ,и я получил словарь,но после возникала проблема как все это записать ,построчно. Т.е что бы на выходе было :

```
qwerty:80
trash:1337
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно так:

```
In [71]: [':'.join(t) for t in zip(spis_1, spis_2)]
Out[71]: ['qwerty:80', 'trash:1337']
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант:

```py
spis_1 = ["qwerty","trash"]
spis_2 = ["80","1337"]
res = [*map(':'.join, zip(spis_1, spis_2))]
print(res) # ['qwerty:80', 'trash:1337']
```